# Using different scales as fill based on factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
cnt = 100
df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(cnt, mean = 3), rnorm(cnt, mean = 0)),
                 y = rnorm(2 * cnt), g = rep(0:1, each = cnt))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = as.factor(g))) + 
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha = 0.3, geom = "polygon")
```

This creates a filled contour plot based on factor:
[image]

I'd like to use a different fill scale for each contour, such that g = 0 has a red fill while g = 1 has a blue fill.  Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: In general, no, ggplot only allows you to map each aesthetic once. Sometimes you can work around that with some effort, but generally you can't. See, for example, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/lDvsd4yJ0AE).

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid this was the case.  I'll find another way.

Comment: One possible solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791181/density-shadow-around-the-data-with-ggplot2-r/

Comment: @Henrik, yes, that looks like it will work.  I'll try it later today when I get some spare time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already commented by @joran, the basic design in `ggplot` is one scale per `aes`thetic. Work-arounds of various degree of ugliness are therefore required. Often they involve creation of one or more plot object, manipulation of the various components of the object, and then producing a new plot from the manipulated object(s).

Here two plot objects with different `fill` colour palettes - one red and one blue - are created by setting colours in `scale_fill_continuous`. In the 'red' plot object, the red fill colours in rows belonging to one of the groups, are replaced with blue colours from the corresponding rows in the 'blue' plot object.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

# plot with red fill
p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, color = as.factor(g))) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha = 0.3, geom = "polygon") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "grey", high = "red", space = "Lab", name = "g = 0") +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  theme_classic()

# plot with blue fill
p2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, color = as.factor(g))) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha = 0.3, geom = "polygon") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "grey", high = "blue", space = "Lab", name = "g = 1") +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  theme_classic()


# grab plot data
pp1 <- ggplot_build(p1)
pp2 <- ggplot_build(p2)$data[[1]]


# replace red fill colours in pp1 with blue colours from pp2 when group is 2
pp1$data[[1]]$fill[grep(pattern = "^2", pp2$group)] <- pp2$fill[grep(pattern = "^2", pp2$group)]


# build plot grobs
grob1 <- ggplot_gtable(pp1)
grob2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# build legend grobs
leg1 <- gtable_filter(grob1, "guide-box") 
leg2 <- gtable_filter(grob2, "guide-box") 
leg <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(leg1[["grobs"]][[1]],  leg2[["grobs"]][[1]], "first")


# replace legend in 'red' plot
grob1$grobs[grob1$layout$name == "guide-box"][[1]] <- leg


# plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(grob1)
```

[image]

Comment: very nice! How do you use ggsave to save it as a pdf?

Comment: The first few google hits on "grid.draw ggsave" might help you. Good luck!

Comment: They didn't which is why I asked, do you have an exact link? I tried to use the hints from some answers on stackoverflow but it didn't work. I didn't think it would be a big deal otherwise I might have asked a proper question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried the `ggsave` links myself. A non-`ggsave` way would be `pdf("grob1.pdf")`; `grid.newpage()`; `grid.draw(grob1)`; `dev.off()` (adapted from @hadley's answer [**here**](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/ggplot2-Changes-to-grobs-not-saved-to-file-output-td866151.html)). However, things have developed a lot `ggplot2`, `gtable` and `grid.extra`, so I might have missed some obvious solutions here. Good luck!

Comment: @PatrickT, Perhaps [**this issue**](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1015) is relevant for your trouble using `ggsave` on the grob.

Comment: Thanks @Henryk, the ``pdf()`` solution worked. The ``ggsave`` 'workaround' in your second comment I had already tried unsuccessfully (not sure why). Many thanks!

Comment: What if I do not want to have legend?
When in the `theme` I set `legend.position = "none"`, then the step `leg1 <- gtable_filter(grob1, "guide-box") ` throws an error:




`Error in seq.int(w[1], w[2]) : 'from' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: @Henrik i want to add in a third plot, which i've done following what you've done above, but i don't know how to add in the third legend any ideas? `# build plot grobs
grob1 <- ggplot_gtable(pp1)
grob2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
grob3 <- ggplotGrob(p3)
# build legend grobs
leg1 <- gtable_filter(grob1, "guide-box") 
leg2 <- gtable_filter(grob2, "guide-box") 
leg3 <- gtable_filter(grob3, "guide-box")
leg <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(leg1[["grobs"]][[1]],  c(leg2[["grobs"]][[1]], leg3[["grobs"]][[1]]), "first")
# replace legend in 'red' plot
grob1$grobs[grob1$layout$name == "guide-box"][[1]] <- leg`